# Agregar selector personalizado en router-outlet de angular2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, router

vuelvo a angular2 luego de tiempo y veo que hay varios cambios,empezando que directive ya no se encuentra en Component entre otros,trato de hacer lo siguiente agregar el tag dentro de un

```
<list-directory [folders]='folders'></list-directory>
```

Tengo entendido que a partir de angular rc5 y superior , se tienen que declarar los componentes en app.module , este es mi app.module

```
  app.module.ts

import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HomeModule } from './+home/home.module';
import { AboutModule } from './+about/about.module';
import { TodoModule } from './+todo/todo.module';
import {MiUnidadModule } from './miUnidad/miUnidad.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent, XLargeDirective } from './app.component';
import { NavPanelLat} from './navPanelLat/navPanelLat.component';
import { NavPanelSup } from './navPanelSup/navPanelSup.component';
import { ListDirectoryComponent } from './listDirectory/listDirectory.component';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, XLargeDirective,NavPanelSup,NavPanelLat,ListDirectoryComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    HomeModule,
    AboutModule,
    TodoModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MiUnidadModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}

export { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

Siendo NavPanelLat,NavPanelSup y ListDirectoryComponent, componentes que quiero agregar,
cuando lo agrego a mi app.component.html , no tengo problemas.

```
app.component.html

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
      <nav-panel-sup></nav-panel-sup>

 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
     <nav-panel-lat></nav-panel-lat>

 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>  

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    Ota cosa
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero cuando quiero agregar a miUnidadComponent, el cual esta bajo router-outlet ,me sale el problema de

```
miUnidad.component.html

  <nav-panel-lat></nav-panel-lat>


Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'nav-panel-lat' is not a known element:
1. If 'nav-panel-lat' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of th
is module.
2. If 'nav-panel-lat' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to th
e '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("  [ERROR ->]
<nav-panel-lat></nav-panel-lat>"): MiUnidadComponent@0:2 ; Zone: <root> ; Task:
Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
'nav-panel-lat' is not a known element:
1. If 'nav-panel-lat' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of th
is module.
2. If 'nav-panel-lat' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to th
e '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("  [ERROR ->]
```

Como si no estuviera declarado , el cual solo pasa cuando quiero meter los componentes bajo un rout-outlet,intente ponerlo bajo miUnidad.module, pero me sale el mismo error ,este es mi routing module por seacaso.

```
app-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export function getLazyModule() {
  return System.import('./+lazy/lazy.module' + (process.env.AOT ? '.ngfactory' : ''))
    .then(mod => mod[(process.env.AOT ? 'LazyModuleNgFactory' : 'LazyModule')]);
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/miUnidad', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: getLazyModule }
    ])
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según he entendido, lo que haces es declarar todos los componentes y módulos que utilizas en `app.module.ts`. Tienes razón en lo de que tienes que declarar todos los componentes pero no el lugar en el que los declaras. Me explico.

tal y como tienes modularizada la app, tienes los siguientes módulos: SharedModule, HomeModule, AboutModule, TodoModule, AppRoutingModule, MaterialModule y MiUnidadModule. Cada uno de estos módulos debe declarar por si solo los componentes que utiliza y exportar únicamente los que se vayan a utilizar en los módulos que lo importen.

Es decir, como el componente `miUnidad`, que está declarado en `MiUnidadModule`, hace uso de `NavPanelLat`, la decalaración de este componente debe ir en `MiUnidadModule`.

mi-unidad.module.ts:

```
 import { NavPanelLat } from './navPanelLat/navPanelLat.component';

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [ NavPanelLat ],
   exports: [ NavPanelLat ]        // Solo si NavPanelLat se utiliza fuera de este modulo
  })
 export class MiUnidadModule {}
```

Te recomiendo que revises la documentación oficial sobre [NgModules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)